# How to make speak.js handle and load faster?

Tags: javascript, html, text-to-speech

I am using speak.js as a TTS feature in my novel website, it works perfectly with like small sentences but when i try to use it on the novels it usually take like 3 minutes to load, its loading around 1K words in 3-5 minutes I would like to make the loading faster if possible. There is another issue, there is a novel that has like 10K or more words and the TTS client does not load the novel due to it being too big is there any way to work around this?

https://github.com/kripken/speak.js/

Client

```
var speakWorker;
try {
  speakWorker = new Worker('/speakWorker');
} catch(e) {
  console.log('speak.js warning: no worker support');
}

function speak(text, args) {
  var PROFILE = 1;

  function parseWav(wav) {
    function readInt(i, bytes) {
      var ret = 0;
      var shft = 0;
      while (bytes) {
        ret += wav[i] << shft;
        shft += 8;
        i++;
        bytes--;
      }
      return ret;
    }
    if (readInt(20, 2) != 1) throw 'Invalid compression code, not PCM';
    if (readInt(22, 2) != 1) throw 'Invalid number of channels, not 1';
    return {
      sampleRate: readInt(24, 4),
      bitsPerSample: readInt(34, 2),
      samples: wav.subarray(44)
    };
  }

  function playHTMLAudioElement(wav) {
    function encode64(data) {
      var BASE = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
      var PAD = '=';
      var ret = '';
      var leftchar = 0;
      var leftbits = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        leftchar = (leftchar << 8) | data[i];
        leftbits += 8;
        while (leftbits >= 6) {
          var curr = (leftchar >> (leftbits-6)) & 0x3f;
          leftbits -= 6;
          ret += BASE[curr];
        }
      }
      if (leftbits == 2) {
        ret += BASE[(leftchar&3) << 4];
        ret += PAD + PAD;
      } else if (leftbits == 4) {
        ret += BASE[(leftchar&0xf) << 2];
        ret += PAD;
      }
      return ret;
    }

    document.getElementById("audio").innerHTML=("<audio id=\"player\" src=\"data:audio/x-wav;base64,"+encode64(wav)+"\">");
    document.getElementById("player").play();
  }

  function playAudioDataAPI(data) {
    try {
      var output = new Audio();
      output.mozSetup(1, data.sampleRate);
      var num = data.samples.length;
      var buffer = data.samples;
      var f32Buffer = new Float32Array(num);
      for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        var value = buffer[i<<1] + (buffer[(i<<1)+1]<<8);
        if (value >= 0x8000) value |= ~0x7FFF;
        f32Buffer[i] = value / 0x8000;
      }
      output.mozWriteAudio(f32Buffer);
      return true;
    } catch(e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function handleWav(wav) {
    var startTime = Date.now();
    var data = parseWav(wav); // validate the data and parse it
    // TODO: try playAudioDataAPI(data), and fallback if failed
    playHTMLAudioElement(wav);
    if (PROFILE) console.log('speak.js: wav processing took ' + (Date.now()-startTime).toFixed(2) + ' ms');
  }

  if (args && args.noWorker) {
    // Do everything right now. speakGenerator.js must have been loaded.
    var startTime = Date.now();
    var wav = generateSpeech(text, args);
    if (PROFILE) console.log('speak.js: processing took ' + (Date.now()-startTime).toFixed(2) + ' ms');
    handleWav(wav);
  } else {
    // Call the worker, which will return a wav that we then play
    var startTime = Date.now();
    speakWorker.onmessage = function(event) {
      if (PROFILE) console.log('speak.js: worker processing took ' + (Date.now()-startTime).toFixed(2) + ' ms');
      handleWav(event.data);
    };
    speakWorker.postMessage({ text: text, args: args });
  }
}
```

Worker

```
importScripts('/speakGenerator');

onmessage = function(event) {
  postMessage(generateSpeech(event.data.text, event.data.args));
};
```

Generator is super long so ima send a link to the original https://github.com/kripken/speak.js/blob/master/speakGenerator.js

```
  <script src="/speakClient"></script>

  <div class="flex">
    <button id="tts" class="speakButton"><i class="fa-solid fa-volume"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div id="audio"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (async () => {
      try {
        let response = await fetch($$data$$);
        let json = await response.json();
        let index = Number("$$previous$$");

        if (json.type === "Novel") {
          let novelContent = json.chapters[index].novel;

          console.log(novelContent)

          function speakOnClick() {
            speak(novelContent, { amplitude: 100, wordgap: 5, pitch: 50, speed: 175 });
          }

          // Add an event listener for 'click' event
          document.getElementById('tts').addEventListener('click', speakOnClick);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })();
  </script>
```

Is there any way to fix it thank you in advance

I haven't tried messing around with it because I feel like im gonna break it so I haven't tried anything so far, just script the loading on the html page script

Comment: Isn't there a way to split things up? For instance into sentences? When one sentence has completed you load the next?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but I was thinking i could make it so it loads one at a time and then goes into the next one just like you said

Comment: Have you tried the browser native speechsynthesis api? Break things up into paragraphs or something smaller and load an utterance to speak.

Comment: I tried it yesterday, loading the sentences and all that confuses the handler for some reason and skips sentences so I ditched the idea.